# C# models diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, class-diagram

I am looking for a tool like mssql workbench where I can draw my database diagram, but for mssql instead. I am programming in asp.net core and would like to have the tool auto generate a diagram based on my existing models, but also let me modify (but not necessarily generate the classes) the diagram after.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Database Diagrams" feature from MSSQL Management Studio.
Open MSSQL Management Studio, Connect to the SQL Server and select the database. 
Under selected database you should be able to find node "Database Diagram". Right click on it and select "Add new diagram".

You can create diagram from the existing tables in the database and also create new tables as well as modify existing table.

You also can save the diagram as JPEG format.

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was looking for :)